# Create a model based on a Database entity

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm new to AngularJS and I would like to understand how to properly separate the model from the controller. Till now I've always worked with the models inside the controllers. For instance:

```
angular.module("app").controller("customerController", ["Customer", "$scope", "$routeParams",
    function (Customer, $scope, $routeParams){
        $scope.customer = Customer.find({ID:$routeParams.ID});
}]);
```

This function retrieves a customer from the database and exposes that customer to the view. But I would like to go further: for example I could have the necessity to ecapsulate something or create some useful functions to abstract from the row data contained in the database. Something like:

```
customer.getName = function(){
    //return customer_name + customer_surname
};
customer.save = function(){
    //save the customer in the database after some modifies
};
```

I want to create a model for the Customer and reuse that model in lots of controllers. Maybe I could then create a List for the customers with methods to retrieve all customers from the database or something else.

In conclusion I would like to have a model that reflects a database entity (like the customer above) with properties and methods to interact with. And maybe a factory that creates a Customer or a list of Customers. How can I achieve a task like this in AngularJS? I would like to receive some advices for this issue from you. A simple example will be very useful or a theoretical answer that helps me to undestand the right method to approch issues like these in Angular. Thanks and good luck with your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular JS enables you to have automatic view updates when a model change or  an event occur. 
TAHTS IT!

it does so by using $watches  which are a kind of Global Scope java script objects and stay in primary memory through out the life cycle of the angular js web app.

1.Please consider the size of data before putting anything onto the  **$scope because each data object you attach to it does +1 to $watch.** As you are reading from a database you might have 100+ rows with >4 columns and trust me it will eat up client side processing.**Pls do consider the size of your dataset and read about angular related performance issues for huge data set**

2.to have models for your database entity i would suggest having plain javascript classes i.e. dont put everything on $scope (it will avoid un necessay watches! ) http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

3.You wish to fire up events when the user changes the values. For this best i would suggest that if you are using ng-repeat to render the data in your array then use $index to get the row number where the change was done and pass this in ng-click i.e. and use actionIdentifier to distinguish in the kinds of events you want

```
ng-click="someFunc($index,actionIdentifier)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a factory/service to do do the job, check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYFE9/)

html:

```
<div ng-app="users-app">
  <h2>Users</h2>
  <div ng-view ></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
      <p>Users: {{(user || {}).name || 'not created'}}</p>
      <button ng-click='getUser()'>Get</button>
      <button ng-click='saveUser(user)'>Save</button>
  </script>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('users-app', ['ngRoute'])

.factory('Users', function() {
    function User (user) {
        angular.extend(this, user);
    }

    User.prototype.save = function () {
        alert("saved " + this.name);
    }

    return {
        get: function() {
            return new User({name:'newUser'});
        }
    }
})

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {controller:'ListCtrl',templateUrl:'list.html'});
})

.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, Users) {

   $scope.getUser = function() {
        $scope.user = Users.get();
    }
    $scope.saveUser = function(u) {
        u.save();
    }
})
```

Hope that help,
Ron